# Who's interested in a weekly genealogy chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

Who would be interested in a one hour scheduled chat each week, mostly revolving around a different topic each session? The day and time is yet to be decided, but it should optimally be able to include as many interested users as possible. Because of such, the time may vary by the week so everyone has a chance to participate, regardless of location. The topics are also yet to be decided.

We're looking for a show of hands, so if you'd be interested in a semi-focused chat each week, just post an answer with the best times that would work for you and any suggestions for topics.

To chat, simply click the "chat" link at the top of your screen, select the room (not yet created), and you will be connected immediately.

If there's enough people interested, we'll schedule a time and see you there!

Comment: I'm not a fan of chat because it is the Q&A of Stack Exchange that I prefer and think will be its lasting legacy.  I see chat as diluting that focus.

Comment: Although the major part of Stack Exchange is Q&A, SE does support discussion as well. Some people are just more discussion oriented and some topics are just more conducive to chat (such as experiences or lengthy conversations). Chat isn't necessarily removing the SE framework, but can instead augment it when used properly.

Comment: @PolyGeo There are topics -- such as 'What's on your Genealogy Bookshelf' (aka what reference/how-to books do you find most useful) -- that don't make good questions but could make good discussions. Plus, there are things we 'talk' about here on Meta that might benefit from a bit of back-and-forth.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I'm not saying shut down chat but it is not for me - I would rather try to [**increase our question rate**](http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/how-to-increase-our-question-rate).

Comment: @PolyGeo, fair enough -- so would I. (Chat's not my natural habitat, except as a place for extended discussion of a question if the need arises).

Comment: I suspect that several (many?) people who are drawn to SE for the arms-length reading and writing of Q&A will be disinclined to engaged in live Chat. It may be the ultimate irony that Chat could be the most appropriate vehicle for efficient discussion of ways to generate new questions.

Comment: @Fortiter, I almost suggested 'generating new questions' as a topic, but thought I was getting repetitive.

Comment: I'd be interested to join in from time to time, but because (a) I am in Australia and might not be available at a time that suits others and (b) I travel a lot for work, I can't guarantee that I'd participate every time.

Comment: Could the room be open for awhile after the hour is finished for those who didn't make it at the allotted time to put in their two cents?

Comment: Sure. If it gives more people an opportunity to share their ideas, I have no problem with it.